# search form in rails 3 not returning as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

This is my first attempt at trying to implement a simple search form in my rails app, New to rails so forgive me if I have made some major mistakes

I have a search form that looks like this

```
  <%= form_tag({:controller => 'search', :action => 'search'}, {:method => 'get'})  do |s| %>
  <%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
   <%= submit_tag "Search" %>
  <% end %>
```

My controller

```
def search

@countrysearch = Recipe.find(params[:search])
end
```

For now i am outputting my results like so

```
  <h4>output</h4>
  <%= @countrysearch %>
```

I am getting an output but if i search for a word like Wales, i get an error saying could not find by id, but if i search for an id like 17 then i get

```
  #<Recipe:0x97b0fa8>
```

I have looked into the find_by_sql method but my understanding of this is not there yet, im unsre of the syntax to search dependent on the string I enter, though I guess that doesn’t matter as the params are the content of the search field?

If any can help then it would be much appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The model `find` method (`Recipe.find()`) expects the numeric id of the instance (a specific recipe).  But it looks like you're searching by country name.  There are *lots* of ways to do this in Rails. First, however, I assume that your recipe model has an attribute like "country" whose values are like "Wales".

If so, then you could make your search method like this:

```
def search
  @countrysearch = Recipe.find_by_country(params[:search])
end
```

Or alternatively you could use the new approach in Rails 3

```
def search
  @countrysearch = Recipe.where(:country => params[:search])
end
```

Don't use `find_by_sql` -- it will work, and it's not bad, but then you're missing some of the main power of Rails.

There are a couple of other things worth mentioning:

- You'll get an error in the view if the search returns no results.  Before referencing the `@countrysearch` instance variable, test for nil using `if @countrysearch.nil?` or for the positive case `if @countrysearch.present?`
- Chances are there will be more than one recipe from Wales, so expect not an instance of `Recipe` back, but a collection of them -- in your view, iterate using 
  <% @countrysearch.each do |recipe| %>
    <%= recipe.name %>
    ...
  <% end %>
- Similarly, if you use the finder method you should go with `Recipe.find_all_by_country`
- Storing the country name in the Recipe model is not a great practice.  Create a model containing countries.
- You probably want a case-insensitive search ("Wales" != "wales")

Comment: ah thanks you for clearing that up about the method .find, now i get a result returned as #<ActiveRecord::Relation:0xb2d9788c>

Comment: oh and missing ) after search :)

Comment: I was correcting the missing ) and adding more comments that should clarify as you were trying :-).  Using the `each` iterator will force the `<ActiveRecord::Relation>` to do it's thing and actually execute the SQL that does the search.  If for some reason you need the results as an array you can do `@countrysearch = Recipe.where(:country => params[:search]).all`

Comment: brilliant it works :) i wont ask you how i search multiple columns in the model then lol :)... unless you can advise? thanks so much

Comment: Excellent!  So if you want the coolest and simplest way to do multi-field search and sort, check out [Ernie Miller's brilliant Ransack gem here](https://github.com/ernie/ransack).